# After Robocopy backup, explorer.exe is using 100% of CPU on critical fileserver

Tags: windows-server-2008, cpu-usage

Last night, I did a routine manual backup using Robocopy backing up and entire drive of a critical file server (windows 2008 r2) to a backup server on the same network. This morning (around an hour ago), I noticed the drive filled up on our backup server on our Zabbix monitoring system and Robocopy was showing a "not enough space on disk" error as expected. So I CTRL + C'd to cancel.

After I canceled, I noticed Zabbix told me that the critical file server was at 100% CPU usage! I checked Task Manager and noticed that explorer is giving a 58%-75% reading but not 100%. All other processes are at 0 or 1% not totaling 100%, but the total CPU usage is still at 100%.

I can't reboot the server unless I absolutely have to because hundreds of employees depend on this file server. I did some research and found that it may be due to a broken shortcut on the desktop, but I don't have any broken shortcuts.

Any ideas?

Comment: kill explorer.exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely terminate `explorer.exe` without causing downtime on your system...just verify who owns the process before doing at as it does kill the GUI in Windows.

Task Manager doesn't always accurately account for "kernel" CPU time in processes, so the columns won't always add up. If you go to `View -> Show Kernel Times`, it'll show the kernel CPU usage in red.

Comment: Yes it's under my account name. I will terminate then. Thanks.

Comment: That did it. Just wanted to be reassured because there were several people logged in too. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great. If you wouldn't mind marking this as your answer that'd help further people, too. :)

Comment: You got it. Just need to wait 2 minutes.